# UpdateView using foreignkey in Django

Tags: django, django-generic-views

Is there a way that instead of `pk` i will select the model data by `foreign key` in UpdateView? It is no doubt it works on the `id` of the data but what if i will select the data object in the model using `foreign key`  condition? How would i do that?

Here is my UpdateView class:

```
class SettingsProfileView(UpdateView):
    model               = UserInfoModel
    template_name       = 'site/views/settingsprofile.html'
    form_class          = UserInfoForm
```

I try to put:

```
def getquery_set(self):
   return self.model.objects.filter(users_id = self.kwargs['pk'])
```

but still its refering to get the data by `primary key`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method is [**`.get_queryset(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_queryset) not <s>`getquery_set`</s>, but nevertheless, this will not work, since the filtering is done in the [**`.get_object(..)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_object).

You thus can work with:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

class SettingsProfileView(UpdateView):
    model = UserInfoModel
    template_name = 'site/views/settingsprofile.html'
    form_class = UserInfoForm

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        if queryset is None:
            queryset = self.get_queryset()
        return get_object_or_404(queryset, user_id=self.kwargs['pk'])
```

Comment: thanks it work. I'm just new in django framework and I came from flask. It is hard for me to understand the generic vews at the first time i study it. but now i totally get the point and the use. I used to be more dependent in flask unlike django you can't do anything unless the framework will allow it.